# How to use <include> element to reuse the schema defined in another schema?

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, xsd, include

I have an xsd which contains UserDetails (UserDetails.xsd).

I have another Xsd which contains a list of UserDetails (UserDetailsList.xsd).

How to use  element (or something similar) to reuse the schema defined in the UserDetails.xsd?

I've tried the below but it doesn't compile:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns="" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="userDetailsList">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:include schemaLocation="UserDetails.xsd"/>     
      </xs:sequence>     
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>  
</xs:schema>
```

UPDATE:

Sorry, found it myself - will close it!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns="" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:include schemaLocation="UserDetails.xsd"/>
  <xs:element name="userDetailsList">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="userDetails" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded" type="userDetailsType" />
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>  
</xs:schema>
```

Comment: You should answer your own question and accept it if you've found the solution. Editing the solution to your question into your question doesn't let the rest of us know you've solved your problem :)

Answer (score 0):

solved by OP himself:

Marking it as community wiki to avoid reputation from upvotes (just incase) ..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns="" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:include schemaLocation="UserDetails.xsd"/>
  <xs:element name="userDetailsList">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="userDetails" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded" type="userDetailsType" />
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>  
</xs:schema>
```